# Lravel 5, Behat, Mink: base_url parameter is not read from behat.yml

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bdd, behat

I am using **Laravel 5**, **Behat** and **Mink Extension for Laravel**. `composer.json` piece for installation of the components is:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "behat/behat": "^3.0",
    "behat/mink": "^1.6",
    "behat/mink-extension": "^2.0",
    "laracasts/behat-laravel-extension": "^1.0"
}
```

I have set the base URL in `behat.yml`, the whole contents of the file:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Laracasts\Behat:
            # env_path: .env.behat
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://localhost/leaveTracker/public
            default_session: laravel
            laravel: ~
```

Please note that I have set the base_url here as:

```
            base_url: http://localhost/leaveTracker/public
```

Also I have written this sample feature:

```
Feature: Viewing the list of employees
In order to operate the employees' data
As a user
I need to see the list of employees

Scenario: I have the option to add employee
    Given I am on page "/employee"
    Then the current URL should be "http://localhost/leaveTracker/public/employee"
```

And the respective part for `FeatureContext.php` is:

```
/**
 * @Then the current URL should be :arg1
 */
public function theCurrentUrlShouldBe($arg1)
{
    PHPUnit::fail($this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl());
}
```

Here I get the following an error that is normal to me:

```
Scenario: I have the option to add employee                                      
Given I am on page "/employee"                                                 
Then the current URL should be "http://localhost/leaveTracker/public/employee" 
    Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
    --- Expected
    +++ Actual
    @@ @@
    -'http://localhost/employee'
    +'http://localhost/leaveTracker/public/employee'
```

**So now my question is:** why the `base_url` is not read from `behat.yml` file?

**Note:** I have also tried to set `base_url: https://test.com`, but yet it takes the `http://localhost/employee`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into same kind of problem when updating from Behat 2.x to Behat 3.x

behat.yml: [defining base_url]

```
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: 'http://localhost/index.php'
```

Within your Context classes who extend from RawMinkContext call:

```
$this->visitPath($url);
```

That function combines `$config['base_url']` with `$url`. Calling `$this->getSession()->visit($url)` browses to plain `$url`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Given I am on page "/employee"
```

Try with:

```
Given I am on "/employee"
```

I don't know about Laravel but this is how we do in symfony:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'http://localhost/myproject/web/app_test.php/'
```

When you call command below, you should expect to see base URL above so what happens in your case?

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{

    // In one of you methods run this
    echo $this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl();

}
```